# views in fragment not displaying sometimes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this navigation drawer with different fragments, The image below gives a visual description. The issue i am having is when i visit another view like the profile view and return to the dashboard view, the dashboards' home tab shows up empty till i visit one of the other tabs and return to it, then it displays the items in it. Please see the second image. All i get in my monitor is a `"E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"` error.

[image]

[image]

Below is my code for the dashboard home tab

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablayout, null);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    prepareDataResource();
    titleList();

    topLevel rta = new topLevel(getFragmentManager(),fragmentList,titleList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(rta);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    setTabIcons();

    return x;
}
```

*Code for the Dashboard Fragment that houses home,PTA, incidents tabs

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablayout, null);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    prepareDataResource();
    titleList();

    topLevel rta = new topLevel(getFragmentManager(),fragmentList,titleList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(rta);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    setTabIcons();

    return x;
}
```

Comment: That logcat error is the key to your issue. Is there a RecyclerView in your home tab, or in the parent activity? If so, please post the code where you are setting its adapter. The adapter is not being attached to the RecyclerView before the view is displayed, so Android skips displaying the layout entirely... probably an issue with Fragment/Activity lifecycle and you're simply making the call in the wrong place.

Comment: @Demonsoul i have no recyclerview in the home tab or the parent activity, i have posted the code for the parent view which is the dashboard fragment above

Comment: Usually you should populate the drawer in activity which host your tabs/viewpager. I guess you init your drawer in `home` fragment. Can you tell us where did you call setAdapter method?

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? @Demonsoul